# After Scanner.hasNext()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I don't know if this is a noob question, but in my code:

```
void process() {
   ...
   while (input.hasNext()) {
       \\ DO WHATEVERITNEEDSTODO
   }
   out.close();
   ...
}
```

It does everything in the while statement, but afterwards it doesn't go on and therefore doesn't close. Even when I put System.out.println("Hello hello") instead of out.close() as a simple check, it doesn't print "Hello hello"

I'm basically trying to have out.close() happen after my input has gone through everything. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: We're going to need to see what the code in the `while` does

Comment: Does `input.hasNext()` ever return false? If not it will stay in the loop forever.

Comment: Please show the code for "input.hasNext()".

Comment: What resourse is your Scanner reading from ? The `System.in` or ... ?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott You do realize that the poster is talking about the library function `Scanner#hasNext()`, right?

Comment: @DennisMeng Aah, so he is...  /hides in shame

Comment: Do you ever call input.Next()? If not the iterator will never move forward and input.hasNext() will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs for `hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29), "This method may block while waiting for input to scan." I'd guess you're running a Scanner on some kind of input that never ends (like maybe System.in?). Therefore, you'd see the body of the loop executing, but eventually, you run out of things to process, and it hangs forever waiting for there to either be a "next" or not.

To put it another way, just because there's nothing presently available to read from the Scanner's underlying stream, it doesn't mean there will never be. As long as the stream remains open, more content may eventually become available to be read.